Configure Application Insights Proxy
I have a C# .Net 8 Console Application that is running a HostedService. In my DI configuration I've configured ApplicationInsights using a combination of the AddApplicationInsightsTelemtryWorkerService
and AddApplicationInsights.
How do I configure a proxy to be used for sending the logs to the Application Insights workspace? I can't set this using the http_proxy or https_proxy
environment variables as there are other applications running on the target server, so I need to be able to configure the proxy settings in the application.
